# Do I have to install drivers for Windows7 system?

Tags: windows-7, windows-7-x64

```
Hi all,
```

I am not sure if this is the right place to ask this question. But I didn't know where else to post this. I have Ubuntu in my laptop. I want to remove it and install Windows 7. My question is, shall I have to install any drivers after installing OS? Also, does Windows7 comes with built in MS Office??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yeah, normally you need to install drivers by yourself. Some Drivers will be catched by windows update, but normally you have to download the drivers on the manufactor-website and install them. Please check if there are driver availible for windows 7 befor you install it.
2. Windows 7 have no built in office solution.  You have to buy and install microsoft office or your libre oder openoffice.

Comment: Are the drivers OS specific or machine specific?

Answer (score 0):

both. you have to get the correct driver for the machine with matching os.

For example Graphiccarddriver for Radeon m9400 for acer xyz notebook for windows 7 64bit